# Not able to connect to other hosts inside a docker container

Tags: docker, networking, routes, centos, centos7

> I solved it, se the edit at the end of the description.

I'm using Centos7 as a host and running docker version 17.05.0-ce

I'm able to pull images on to the host. 
from inside a contiainer I'm able to ping the docker interface, I'm also able to ping the host machine. But thats it, I'm not able to ping any other hosts, not the dns on the local network, not google, nothing. I guess it's something with the routing, but I can't figure it out. 
Anyone got an idea?
This is (obviously) not about connecting to other containers on the same host. but probably a problem with the routing or configuration in docker

```
jonmat ~ $ docker -v 
Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be

# pulling images works fine, so the engine can connect to the internet
jonmat ~ $ docker pull alpine
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
ff3a5c916c92: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:7b848083f93822dd21b0a2f14a110bd99f6efb4b838d499df6d04a49d0debf8b
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest

# pinging google dns from the host is is no problem
jonmat ~ $ ping -c1 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=5.16 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.160/5.160/5.160/0.000 ms

# pinging google dns from inside the container won't work, probably some kind of routing issue?
jonmat ~ $ docker run -it --rm alpine ping -c1 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

EDIT:
I found the problem myself. someone other than me have also been using the host, and they added the option "--ptables=false" to dockerd, i removed this and it solved my problem.

Comment: This is the desired behavior. Create docker network and join containers together. Please read to understand [how container communication works](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/). Or use `docker-compose` to create a stack (it will create a docker network for you).

Comment: No, it's not the desired behaviour, i'm not trying to connect between containers but with hosts outside the docker-host. I have edited the examples, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @JonasMattsson did you manage to solve this problem? Fresh docker install from Centos has this problem

Comment: @idchlife yes i did, read the end of my question where I explain my findings on how i solved this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your container is running with name alpine, can you try below command

```
docker exec -t alpine ping 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: I don't think the pseudo terminal is going to help with my routing issues

Answer (score 0):

In the example given above, seems you are missing some options, try this

```
docker run -it --rm -t alpine ping -c1 8.8.8.8
```

If container is already running use docker exec like posted above. (I would like to combine both answers, but unfortunately I am not finding option to delete and add it in the first answer itself)

Refer the [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/commandline/exec/#parent-command) for more details

Comment: I don't get why a psudo terminal would help me?